# How do I specify a client certificate to moped in mongoid.yml?

Tags: mongodb, ssl, mongoid

I am trying to set up mongoid to connect to a mongodb server using ssl with client certificates for authentication.  However, I cannot find a comprehensive reference for the options in mongoid.yml .

For example, I found this: [How to enable SSL/TLS in Mongoid 3 client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22873735/how-to-enable-ssl-tls-in-mongoid-3-client) - which references a ssl: true option (which seems to work), but that mongoid.yml option does not appear to be documented anywhere I can find.

I am able to connect using the client certificate using the mongo shell.  If I leave out the ssl: true option in mongoid.yml, at the server I get "AssertionException handling request, closing client connection: 17189 The server is configured to only allow SSL connections"

If I do use the ssl: true option, I get "ERROR: no SSL certificate provided by peer; connection rejected" suggesting that the ssl: true option is working.

So, is there a way to provide the client cert/key and ca cert to mongoid using mongoid.yml?  Or is there another way to make the connection to the mongod and provide the connection to mongoid?  Or is it simply not possible to use ssl client certificates for authentication with mongoid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was posted several years ago, before the Mongoid gem was taken over by the MongoDB team.  Mongoid 5 is a significant upgrade, and the documentation has also been dramatically improved.

I updated my applications to use Mongoid 5; the biggest change was that I had been using the lower level driver (Moped) for some operations, for better efficiency.  However, with Mongoid 5, the standard ruby MongoDB driver is used, so I had to rewrite the code that used the lower level driver.

However, it was well worth it.  Among the improvements in Mongoid 5 is documentation that clearly explains how to provide the client cert/key and ca cert to the Mongoid driver at https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/tutorial/mongoid-installation/

You will also want to provide the matching configuration for the mongod server, which is explained at  https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/configure-ssl/

Also, as indicated on that latter page, as of MongoDB distributions now include support for SSL.